# creating new elements in existing xml file using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to xslt, Please help: 
i want to create new elements in existing xml file using xslt. Please find the below sample code.

Existing output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
<class>
<student>Jack</student>
<student>Harry</student>
<student>Rebecca</student>
<teacher>Mr. Bean</teacher>

</class>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="class.xsl"?>
<class>
<student>Jack</student>
<student>Harry</student>
<student>Rebecca</student>
<teacher>Mr. Bean</teacher>
<professor>SaiBaba</professor>
</class>
```

Comment: Please post your xslt as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the simplest and shortest template including logic towards your question would be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity-copy">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="class">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <professor>SaiBaba</professor>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`@*` matches all attributes

`node()` is a function to match all elements on child-axes with type

- element
- text-node
- processing-instruction (PI) node
- comment node

First template named `indentity-copy` is a 1:1 copy from source to output. See more infos at [Wiki here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform).

The second template matches your element `class`, copies itself, and adds the element `professor`. Alternativ way: You can create the elements in a more strict version via XSL commands to reduce/avoid whitespace or namespace problems:

```
<xsl:element name="professor">
    <xsl:text>SaiBaba</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Thank you uL1. Its working but when open then xml file it is not representing like xml tag i mean like <Professor>SaiBaba</Professor>. Im getting only elements values not like element name and value. Could you please help in this regard.

Comment: Where do you execute the xslt? Browser? Editor? Try `<xsl:output method="xml" />` after opening `<xsl:stylesheet.. >`. Please post your result.

Comment: Thanks one more time for quick response.I got this one. For this i opened the xml file in IE and i used F12 debugger in that im able to see the expected out put.  here i have one more question if i want add the sub element for existing element then how to proceed it ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show your second input-casd and expected output. So i ca adjust my answer